# Saving sortable to mysql with ajax jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, jquery-ui

I have a page with multiple drag&drop boxes, that works great, the thing that does not work are the links in the boxes. I would appreciate if someone could help me :). So I have a page where people can drag&drop boxes (it works fine, as I said before), the links inside the boxes are sortable aswell, but I can't seem to get them to save the values to mysql. I think there is a conflict between the two drag&drops, maybe I am doing it wrong, 'cause I haven't used ajax and jquery before.

```
//here is the jquery where I need to add some ajax
$(function() {
$('.dragbox-content').sortable({ 
  connectWith: '.dragbox-content',
  update: function(event, ui) {
        var order=$(this).attr('id');
        alert(order);  // I get the order alert and it has one value that I need, but I need the sort order aswell                         
  }
  });                 
});

//this is the <div> that has the links in them and mysql query that gets the values
//from two different databases, one is for the boxes and the other for links.
//boxes db id = links title_id
echo '<div class="dragbox-content" id="order'.$widget['id'].'"';'>''</div>';

$sql10 = "SELECT u.*, w.id, w.link_address, w.link_name FROM db_boxes u LEFT 
JOIN db_links w ON u.link_id = w.id  WHERE 
(u.username = '$username' AND u.link_id !='0' AND w.title_id = '".$widget['id']."' 
AND w.link_name !='pilt' AND w.rights = '0') OR 
(u.username = '$username' AND u.link_id !='0' AND w.title_id = '".$widget['id']."' 
AND w.link_name !='pilt' AND w.rights LIKE '%26%') ORDER BY w.id ASC";
      $result10 = mysql_query($sql10) or die (mysql_error());
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result10)) {
        $link_id = $row['id'];
        $link_address = $row['link_address'];
        $link_name = $row['link_name'];
        $title_id = $row['title_id'];
      ?>
      <div class="move" id="<?php echo $link_id;?>">
      <span class="link_style">
      <div><a href="<?php echo $link_address; ?>"><?php echo $link_name;?>     </a></div</span></div>
```

I just need somebody to tell me how can I save tile_id and sort_order to boxes database with ajax on every click a user makes on that page

Comment: [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

`$('#page').click(
  function(){
    $.ajax(/*...*/);
  }
);`

Comment: I have tried something like that, but it does not work. I forgot to mention that when I use that sort of updating with ajax everything stops working including the boxes that work great if I don't have any ajax written to the other sortable.

Comment: How about Ozerich's code with `mouseup` instead of `click`? That way the drag&drop isn't interrupted, but the query is sent when the drag ends

Comment: Tried, but no success. Maybe I am doing something wrong with trying to save, if someone could give me an example what to write between /*...*/ in Ozerich's code. Everything I have tried so far ends up with the hole page not working right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my example below:

http://jsfiddle.net/gRoberts/vMy7r/

```
$(function () {
    $('ul').sortable({
        update : function(e, ui) {
            var ul = $(ui.item).closest('ul');
            var index = 0;
            var toPost = {};
            ul.find('> li').each(function() {
                index++;
                $(this).find('input').val(index);               
                toPost[$(this).find('input').attr('name')] = index;
            });                  
            $.ajax({
                url : '/echo/json/',
                data : toPost,
                type : 'POST',
                dataType : 'json',
                success : function(resp) {
                    alert(resp);
                },
                error : function() {
                    alert('There was a problem');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
​
```

The above example can be used in two ways, if you remove the `$.ajax` it will update hidden form fields which you can then post normally.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but once again no luck. I don't know what's wrong, as soon as I add anything to the link sortable the boxes stop working. It's really getting on my nerves, I've been stuck with this since monday and I just don't know what to do anymore..

Comment: Do you happen to have a live link we can look at?

Comment: No, but I missed something in your code before and now I changed it and it alerts me with 'There was a problem' if I try to drag a link from one box to another. So I guess I am getting closer. :)

Comment: Yup, that means the code is calling `update` now but if you've simply copied my example, then you will be trying to post to `/echo/json/` which i'm sure doesn't exist on your server ;)

Comment: If you are willing to help me, I'll get a link the latest by tomorrow ?

Comment: Sure, just send it over and I'll take a look ;)

Comment: 'Real code' shows pictures of my code what I am using on localhost, but the first page shows what I am trying to do..

Comment: Maybe you can help me with 'UpdateLinks.php', right now sortable is working, but not saving to database.

Comment: 1) UpdateLinks.php doesn't exist, causing the Ajax error. 2) In the LI's you want to sort, you need to add a hidden field. This will contain the ID of the item you want to sort, plus the order value. i.e. `<input type="hidden" name="Order[<?= $row['link_id']; ?>]" value="<?= $row['link_order']; ?>" />`

Comment: Then, within UpdateLinks.php, you simply need to receive a `POST` and loop through and update the rows, i.e. `foreach($_POST['Order'] as $Link_ID => $Order) { echo "$Link_ID is at $Order"; // also update database }`

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try, but I want to do it without the input and <li>. I want to use div's, so it's going to take some time :)

Comment: Either way, you will need something to contain the unique id for that link so that you can match the link to the new order. This is why I use hidden inputs. Hope it works out for you ;)